# Fastify async try catch does not resolve

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, try-catch, fastify

I have simple route:

```
fastify.post('/subscribe', {
  schema: subscribeSchema,
  handler: async (req, reply) => {

    try {
      const events = req.body.events;
      const allEventsProcessingData = await Promise.all(events.map(async (ev) => {
        return {
          event: ev,
          feedEventsData: await getFeedEventData(ev),
          feedMainMarketsData: await getFeedEventMainMarketsData(ev),
        }
      }));

      // process HTML by events data
      // allEventsProcessingData
      const compiledHTML = '';


      return reply.send(compiledHTML);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('e', e);
      return reply.send(HTTP_RESPONSES.FAIL);
    }
  }
});
```

When error happens, the response does not send, why is it? And how to send it? Tried this https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/1864#issuecomment-534233381, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide us your `subscribeSchema` ? I tried to reproduce your case with a generic one and it seems to work. ie https://gist.github.com/mxncson/f180c1c9726f02b9617d44263b7d47a9

Comment: Are you using fastify V2?

Comment: This is a schema https://gist.github.com/AlexanderTserkovniy/092f17ab1a7dc3f5a8cd32799dd153d6. Hmm seems to work for me either, I tried everything what I did while it was not working, then somehow it started to work, so I do not know the real reason of the issue, but it was the way I describe it. Anyway thanks all.

Comment: When using async/await syntax, either call reply.send or directly return a value to avoid unexpected behaviour. Check the docs: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/#async-await